# How to pass info from a child component to a function in the parent component? (REACT NATIVE)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a presentational child component with 10 buttons like so

```
  <Button onPress={...} title="1" />
  <Button onPress={...} title="2" />
  <Button onPress={...} title="3" />
  ...
```

I have a function in the parent component that needs to know the number of each button.

```
checkNumber(e) {
  ...
  return number
}
```

How do I get the number from the child component's button without writing 10 functions?

Comment: can you provide more detailed code, maybe the parent component and how you are calling child component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a concept called callbacks in React or react-native

You will have event handler function in parent component. If your event handler function is a regular function then you make sure you bind it in constructor or change it to an arrow function

Since you are using normal function you need binding in constructor like

```
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.checkNumber = this.checkNumber.bind(this);
  }

  checkNumber(e, number){
       ...
     return number
   }
```

Or use an arrow function. You no need to bind it manually in constructor

```
  checkNumber = (e, number) => {
       ...
     return number
   }
```

Now pass down checkNumber function as a prop to your presentional component like

```
    <PresentationalComponent checkNumber={this.checkNumber} />
```

And in your presentational component

```
     <Button  onPress={e => this.props.checkNumber(e, 1)} title=“1”/>
    <Button onPress={e => this.props.checkNumber(e, 2)} title="2" />
      .......
      .......
      <Button onPress={e => this.props.checkNumber(e, 10)} title="10”/>
```

Please excuse me if there are any typo error because I am answering in my mobile :)